# Counting "something" in multiple text files in one folder

Tags: python, file, text, count

I am trying to count the number times "Tmp" occurs in a file and what file the count belongs to.  I created a script that works but I have to setup the input file and output directory for each file.  To improve it I would like the script to go through each file in a folder after setting it up once.

I have been experimenting with:

```
import tkFileDialog
import glob
import os
directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.*")):
    open(infile, "r").read()
    infile.count("Tmp")
```

Currently I am counting the number of times "Tmp" occurs in the file name and not the actual file, when I type:

```
print infile
```

it outputs the contents of the text files but not the directory?  I am just confused on where to go or what to do.

Comment: `import tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` - no, just no.

Comment: import tkFileDialog.askdirectory() yep that was a typo should be import tkFileDialog

Comment: this is invalid code, your example should not be compiling and running. You can not just import something with the brackets as you execute it.

Comment: I am new to python but I think you are pointing out how I forgot the "import os" part?

Comment: i am pointing out this: `import tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` which you already corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use os.walk rather than glob:

```
import tkFileDialog
import os
import os.path
import re

directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)

        with open(path) as file:
            contents = file.read()

            print path[:30], contents.count('Tmp'), re.findall('Tmp\d{5}', contents)
```

Comment: @Jeff I'd love to know what is not working.  Do you get an error?  What happens?

Comment: Hmmm, it is working for me today, I must have mistyped something last night.  I was able to manipulate Cesars to condense the file name, from 90+ to the first 30 characters, how could I do the same with this code, and if possible list all of the "Tmp12345" in each file.  My original script used re.findall('[Tmp]+\d(5)',infile)   to do this.  This may be getting a little too far over my head.

Comment: I changed the code to do what you're looking for.  Keep in mind that if your on a *nix system, grep can do everything you need (if you just need to print this stuff out).

Comment: Thanks for your help I am going to mess around with this and see if I can fully grasp the process here, all in all these 7 lines replace 20 lines I originally began with.  No nix system here, I have been using the print >> to force everything to a text file.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

```
data = open(infile, 'r').read()
print data.count('Tmp')
```

Comment: The problem with this is there's no way to close infile, which would be an issue if the directory had thousands of files in it.

Comment: This works for counting every instance of "Tmp", it's something I can work with.  Thanks

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import glob
import tkFileDialog


directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()        

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*')):
    if os.path.isfile(infile):
        f = open(infile)
        print os.path.split(infile)[-1], f.read().count('Tmp')
```

Comment: You have to open infile before you can read it, and I think you mean `infile.read().count('Tmp')`

Comment: It should be count('Tmp'), not count(directory).

Comment: I have been using this method and it has been working, I see I am not the only one who has typos :)